# Can I get inverted (i.e. Mac-like) scrolling on my touchpad?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

I have two-finger scrolling enabled on my touchpad. Moving my fingers up scrolls up and moving them down scrolls down. I would like to have the direction of scrolling inverted, in much the same way the Mac does it. Can I do this? How?

Comment: dconf editor is the best way, but I think he meant to check, not uncheck it. Also , I tried, files(nautilus) would not ignore this setting on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just paste

```
pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

inside a file named: **.Xmodmap** and save it to your home folder :) **Don't forget to log out and back in**

Comment: Thanks. I'd point out to readers that the key thing here is switching 4 and 5 in the order.

Comment: You may also want to switch 6 and 7. Notice that this doesn't work as consistently in 12.04 as it did in 11.10. Some applications (such as nautilus, gedit and the software center) ignore this setting.

Comment: for Xfce, see this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/690512/how-to-enable-natural-scrolling-in-xfce4#853262

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the best way to do this is by using dconf-editor:

- Open Terminal
- Type in *deconf-editor* and hit Enter
- Now go to **org>gnome>settings-daemon>peripherals>touchpad** and uncheck **natural scroll**

Here's a screenshot of deconf-editor after making changes:

[image: dconf-editor]