# How to enable natural scrolling in xfce4?

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, xfce, scrolling

Is there any setting to enable *natural scrolling* for my touchpad?

I can find the setting under *XFCE settings* for the mouse, but it doesn't work for the touchpad. Is there a way to enable it for the latter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I searched a lot and also found a bugreport about it, but the solution was easy:

**You have to select the Touchpad-device in the selectbox at the top of the mouse-settings.**

(It was a bit hard, to find, because I didn't expect that the settings for mouse and touchpad are separately configureable.)

---

On older xfce versions, where the setting doesn't exist, check the value with

```
synclient | grep VertScrollDelta
```

and use the negative value, you find there (for example -58 instead of 58).

The best method that have worked for me to make this **reboot-safe** is to add your changes into `Xsession.d`, so it will load automatically for all users when you log into X:

(the file doesn't exists, so you can name it whatever you want. The numbers on the left means the order in which it will be executed in comparison with the other files.)

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession.d/80synaptics
```

Add just the synclient commands in that file:

```
synclient VertScrollDelta=-58
```

(should be owned by root, with permissions 644)

```
chmod 644 /etc/X11/Xsession.d/80synaptics
```

---

There is still something odd: the horizontal scrolling is still wrong, This can be fixed with:

```
echo 'pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 9 10 11 12' >> .Xmodmap
xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

Answer (score 33):

This is a known bug: [LP:1368402](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1368402)

A good and simple solution (workaround) that allows to use natural scrolling in **every application** (including Chrome and Gnome ones), tested on Xenial 16.04, is the following.

First disable *Reverse scroll direction* from the *XFCE mouse settings*: `Settings > Mouse and Touchpad > Reverse scroll direction`.

Then, run in a terminal:

```
synclient
```

It will output a list of key-value pairs like this:

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 97
    RightEdge               = 2335
    TopEdge                 = 89
    BottomEdge              = 1575
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 129
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 100
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 58
    HorizScrollDelta        = 58
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0678887
    TouchpadOff             = 1
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 14
    VertHysteresis          = 14
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 1216
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 1364
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Search the key: `VertScrollDelta` and check its value.
If its e.g. 58, set then it to -58 with the following command:

```
synclient VertScrollDelta=-58
```

If you want to do the same with the horizontal scroll, search instead for the key: `HorizScrollDelta` and invert it in the same way:

```
synclient HorizScrollDelta=-58
```

[Edit]

As pointed by [rubo77](https://askubuntu.com/users/34298/rubo77), this doesn't last after a reboot. If you want it to become the default, create a script like the following `fix_scroll.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
synclient VertScrollDelta=-58
synclient HorizScrollDelta=-58
```

Then add `fix_scroll.sh` to your startup applications:

```
Settings > Session and Startup > Application Autostart > Add
```

Credit goes to: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=233135&p=1236836&sid=394bf7ad96c3ba102949bac4dd404a1a

Comment: Please mark this answer as the proper one, as this is fixing the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

With Xfce 4.12 or above, you can go to **Mouse settings** and select **Reverse scroll direction**. The setting is under Mouse but it also reverses the scrolling direction for the touchpad.

Comment: I know, but does it also reverse the horizontal scrolling ?

Comment: @rubo77 No, vertical only.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work on every application, especially it doesn't work with Gnome ones

Answer (score 0):

To get natural scrolling, you can add

```
Option "VertScrollDelta" "-71"
Option "HorizScrollDelta" "-71"
```

to the xorg.conf for the input device, which could be the default `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`, or it could be your own `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-magic-touchpad.conf` like

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Apple Magic Trackpad"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchUSBID "05ac:0265"
    Driver "synaptics"
    Option "FingerLow" "2"
    Option "FingerHigh" "2"
    Option "VertScrollDelta" "-71" 
    Option "HorizScrollDelta" "-71"
EndSection
```

Increasing the number -71 to eg. -111 will slow down the scrolling speed.

Comment: Why don't you just select the Touchpad-device in the selectbox at the top of the mouse-settings?

Comment: @rubo77 Now its cleared

Comment: It seems you're the creator of the mentioned YouTube video. You *must disclose that affiliation in the post*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).